# Is it possible to read the text from browser window pop up in Robotframework?

Tags: selenium, robotframework

My scenario:

I have to perform some action, after which the system will be generating a password string. That string will be showing in a window pop up - my question is, how to read that password?

Comment: Is it an operating system popup? Is it a browser pop-up?

Comment: Browser pop up,

Comment: any idea? please help

Comment: What kind of a popup - an html modal, or a browser native one (like from javascript `alert()`)?

Comment: browser pop up. Exactly Alert..

Answer (score 2):

There is a keyword for that in the SeleniumLibrary - [`Handle Alert`](http://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Handle%20Alert), which will return you the content and deal with the alert:

```
${the text}=    Handle Alert
```

Note it accepted a `timeout` argument, for how much time to wait for that alert.